# How can Linux "at" be used to open a gnome-terminal window?

Tags: gnome-terminal, at

Using "at" to execute a shell command that writes to a file works. Using it to open a gnome-terminal does not work.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

A file containing a command to write the date to a file was created and made executable.

date-file.sh: `date > date.txt`

This line was entered.
`at now -f date-file.sh`

As expected, the file date.txt was created and contained the date string.

The (redacted) output of `sudo systemctl status atd` showed

```
May 16 05:25:25 - atd[720411]: pam_unix(atd:session): session opened for user - by (uid=1)
May 16 05:25:25 - atd[720411]: pam_unix(atd:session): session closed for user -
```

A file containing a command to open a gnome-terminal was created and made executable.

open-term.sh: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal`

This line was entered. `at now -f open-term.sh`

No error was reported in the terminal, but nothing seemed to happen. No gnome-terminal window opened.

The (redacted) output of `sudo systemctl status atd` showed

```
May 16 05:31:32 - atd[720500]: pam_unix(atd:session): session opened for user - by (uid=1)
May 16 05:31:32 - atd[720500]: pam_unix(atd:session): session closed for user -
May 16 05:31:32 - atd[720500]: Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory
```

Both command files are in the current directory, and the gnome-terminal command is given with an absolute path, so I don't understand the cause of the "No such file or directory" error.

Can the "at" command be used to open a terminal window?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The "No such file or directory" error is because `atd` can't find a mail program to use, not because it can't find your command. If you run `at now -Mf open-term.sh`, the message will go away. On to why the command isn't working, I haven't had any luck, either.

Comment: A graphical program needs some context, for example which server is going to be used, under which user ... For an unsecured X server something like `DISPLAY=:X command` might get you closer. What is it you're trying to do anyway? There might be another way around. Having a terminal window pop up while using the desktop, possibly grabbing the focus ... it doesn't *sound* well.